# The etymological dictionary of Persian by Mohammad Hassandust

Tags: etymology, dictionary, persian

I'm considering purchasing this book, but it's not available in ebook format, and the price is rather steep. Therefore, I'm eager to ensure its scientific accuracy. I've noticed numerous papers citing it, as well as some critical of its content. Could users here kindly share their opinions on its credibility? Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Hassandust needs to be taken with a grain of salt. I do not generally have much positive to say about Wiktionary, but the Persian etymologies there are often very good. Some competent person has had a lot of input.

Comment: Thank you so much.